# For which angles is inequality true

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

My problem is from Israel Gelfand's Trigonometry textbook.

*Page 48. Exercise 6:*

a) For which angles $\alpha$ is $\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha > \sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha$ ?

b) For which angles $\alpha$ is $\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha \geq \sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha$ ?

*The attempt at a solution:*

I know that $$\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha=(\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha)(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)(\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha)=(\sin\alpha-\cos\alpha)(\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha)=\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha$$

Is this even correct?

I would appreciate some hints on how to approach the problem.

Comment: Pretty good. You proved the equality then the answer for a) is none  and for b) for every angle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, no errors there. As you figured out, $\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha > \sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha$  is not possible.

Comment: Oh, and second is true for all angles since $\sin^4\alpha-\cos^4\alpha=\sin^2\alpha-\cos^2\alpha$ right?

Comment: Exactly my friend.